# add json file style google map in ios

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-maps

I am trying to load a style for my google map from a json file.
But it gives me an error.I added the key for api in `AppDelegate.swift`, I added the keys to `info.plist`, but the card remains standard.

Please tell me where I made a mistake. (*One or more of the map styles failed to load.Error*)

**GoogleMapCustomView.swift**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    //MARK: OVerride
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()

    }

    //MARK: Property
    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MapView", owner: self, options: nil)
        setupMap()
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds

        }
 func setupMap() {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

        mapView.delegate = self as! GMSMapViewDelegate
        contentView = mapView

        //style map
        do{
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json")
            {
               mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
            }else{
                print("unable to find style.json")
            }
        }catch{
            print("One or more of the map styles failed to load.\(error)")
        }

    }
```

**style.json**

```
[
    {
        "featureType": "road",
         "elementType": "fill",
        "stylers": [
            { "color": "#99FF33" }
        ]
]
```

Comment: this - One or more of the map styles failed to load.Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is invalid try

```
[
    {
        "featureType": "road",
         "elementType": "fill",
        "stylers": [
            { "color": "#99FF33" }
        ]
    } <<<<<< you miss this 
]
```

Comment: Oh my carelessness ... Thank you !